# Can numba.jit (nopython) handle array indexing and slicing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I am trying to speed up a simple Python loop using numba.jit. But it seems jit cannot handle basic array indexing and slicing? Is there anything I can do to make this possible? I do not understand how jit can ever be useful if it cannot handle basic numpy arrays.

I am forcing nopython-mode. It works in object-mode, but that does not speed up the code at all so it is nopython mode I need.

The code below is just an example which illustrates the problem. My actual code has the same problem, but has much more loops and iterations such that jit would be very useful.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

n = 100
myarray = np.zeros(n)

@jit(nopython=True)
def compute(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        myarray[i] += 1  # This indexing causes the error.

compute(n)

"""Sample run:
> python jit_test.py
> ...
> Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
> Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.SetItemConstrain object at 0x7f700c89a7d0>:
> Immutable array
> File "jit_test.py", line 10
"""
```

If I try slicing instead a different error appears.

```
# The rest of the code unchanged.
        myarray[:] += 1  # This slicing causes the error.
# The rest of the code unchanged.
"""Sample run:
> python jit_test.py
> ...
> Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
> Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.IntrinsicCallConstrain object at 0x7f297e2a9dd0>:
> Don't know how to create implicit output array with 'A' layout.
> File "jit_test2.py", line 10
"""
```

My build:

```
numba version: 0.19.1
numpy version: 1.9.2
python version: 2.7.10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In numba, global arrays are made static. You get a read-only copy in your method. See:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.20.0/reference/pysemantics.html?highlight=global#global-and-closure-variables

If you want to modify an array, either explicitly pass it in or create it in the function (in newer versions of Numba that do array memory management) and return it.

So for example:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def compute(arr):
    for i in xrange(arr.shape[0]):
        arr[i] += 1

n = 100
myarray = np.zeros(n)

jitcompute = nb.jit(nopython=True)(compute)
```

Then timings:

```
In [12]: %timeit compute(myarray)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.7 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit jitcompute(myarray)
The slowest run took 17.06 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 461 ns per loop
```

A few notes:

- This is obviously a trivial example but it shows how you could define an array outside of the method and then have the function modify it in-place.
- I didn't use the `@jit` decorator here so that I could write the method definition once and time the method with and without numba jit-ing, but `jitcompute` is equivalent to what you would get if you used the decorator on `compute`.
- If you ever benchmark numba code, make sure you run the method one time before doing the timing or else what you'll see is the combination of the time it takes to jit the code and the actual execution time. The second time you run it, you'll only see the execution time.

Comment: I see. Indexing works now. However, arr[:]+=1 does NOT work. arr[:]=1 DOES work. arr[:]=arr[:]+1 does NOT work. arr=arr+1 DOES work. I might be able to work around these limitations by trial and error, but I don't understand what are the rules here? Also, something like arr+arr DOES work, but arr[0:5]+arr[0:5] does NOT work, even though arr2=arr[0:5] DOES work. Is it possible to achieve this without having to perform every slice outside the jit-ed function?

Comment: Also, numba claims to support booleans, but it does NOT treat them like 0s and 1s like Python does? F.ex.: y = np.ones(3); return np.sum(y==y). In python the sum of 3 True's would be 3. But in the jit-ed function this just returns 'True', which is not helpful at all. Do I have to think of the jit-ed function more like C-code and not python at all?