# Slicing Numpy arrays in Numba functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jit, numba

I want to slice a 2D Numpy array within a Numba jit decorated function. The row and column indices are available as lists/numpy arrays. Here is a MWE

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def func(a,rowinds,colinds):
    return np.sum(a[rowinds,colinds])


A = np.random.random([10,10])
rowinds = np.array([0,1,2])
colinds = np.array([3,4,5])

res = func(A,rowinds,colinds)
```

However, this throws up the following error:

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(array(float64, 2d, C), UniTuple(array(int64, 1d, C) x 2))
```

Is there a way around this without manually looping over the elements of `rowinds` or `colinds`?

Comment: do you want to slice or do you want to sum ? if you reproduce this functions just with numpy you're basically summing 3 elements of A, is this what you want?

Comment: @BrunoMagacho: I do want to sum it but in my actual code, the array has a much larger size, and the number of elements I want to sum are much larger. (the example with 3 elements of A is just a MWE to illustrate the issue).

Comment: actually I don't know how those types can be put as indexes, I think that this is a facility of numpy that isn't allowed on numba, this is related to what is described in  [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508628/can-numba-jit-nopython-handle-array-indexing-and-slicing) . There is some problem in loopify over `rowinds` and `colinds` in your application? maybe can be even more efficient for further optimizations